# How to change hover background and foreground color in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am building a eclipse plugin with custom editor. I have implemented text hovering functionality in which user hover on some text then that text will be shown on tooltip like javadocs.

How can i  change the tooltip background and foreground color programmatically?

Comment: Which classes / interfaces are you using for the hover code?

Comment: I am using ITextHover interface for hovering effect in my editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `ITextHover` class also implements `ITextHoverExtension` you can provide the `IInformationControlCreator` in the `getHoverControlCreator()` method.

You can use a simple `IInformationControlCreator` which just returns an instance of `DefaultInformationControl` as the information control. `DefaultInformationControl` has `setForegroundColor` and `setBackgroundColor` methods.